# nettiers data class library not recognized

Tags: c#, console-application, .nettiers

I needed to make a console application using nettiers class libraries. I created a new Console Application project, added references to all the libraries from NetTiers and created an app.config file with all the necessary configurations.  I get intellisense and no errors and everything when I am doing the coding, but when I go to compile the application, I'm getting an error that PPGEDI.Data doesn't exist.

I only have 1 line in the program.cs Main method:

```
PPGEDI.Entities.VansEntity van 
  = DataRepository.VansEntityProvider.GetById(16);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error   93  
   The type or namespace name 'Data' 
   does not exist in the namespace 'PPGEDI' 
   (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

It's frustrating, because I know I've added the assembly reference:

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, with C# and .NET 4.0.  Can anyone give me an idea as to what I need to do to get this to work.

As a note, this works if I use the same statement in a method on an ASPX page in the web application generated by nettiers.

Comment: are you using the .NET client profile in your console app by chance? If so switch to the full .NET 4 as target framework

Comment: Also, unless someone can confirm (I'm not familiar with these libraries), take a look at that assembly in your favorite IL decompiler (Reflector, ilSpy, etc.) and ensure that there *are* actually types in that namespace defined within that assembly.

Comment: .NET versions possible conflict? Did you try to make your project of .NET 2.0 or 3.5?

Comment: @Adam Robinson It is actually in that namespace and class name. BrokenGlass: I am not using the .NET client profile as my framework, I am using the full .NET 4

Comment: @Tigran everything in the entire solution is using .NET 4.0.  I have gone down all the class libraries and have verified this.

Comment: @BrokenGlass, you were absolutely correct.  I double checked and it was set to ".NET Framework Client Profile", I changed it to .NET 4 and it's working now, can you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @BrokenGlass, you were absolutely correct. I double checked and it was
>   set to ".NET Framework Client Profile", I changed it to .NET 4 and
>   it's working now, can you put that as an answer?

You are using the .NET client profile in your console app which is a "minified" version that doesn’t contain all assemblies.

The problem is that when your app adds a reference to a class library that is targeting the full framework, references to the "full" framework assembly will not resolve. This results in the rather non-forthcoming error message that you see. Switching to the the full .NET 4 as target framework will resolve the issue.

For a more in depth overview of the problem and the .NET 4 Client Profile in general also see ["What’s new in .NET Framework 4 Client Profile RTM"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/04/12/what-s-new-in-net-framework-4-client-profile-rtm.aspx)